# Problema recuperar emails NO leídos Javamail

Tags: java, spring-boot, javamail

mi problema es que estoy intentando recuperar los mensajes NO LEÍDOS de una buzón gmail.

El código me funciona si recupero todos los mensajes haciendo uso del método getMessages():

[...]

```
Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
Message[] mensajes = folder.getMessages();
```

En cambio si hago uso de Flags para la lectura de mensajes no leídos me devuelve todos los mensajes del mi buzón, no únicamente los NO leídos:

```
Message[] mensajes = folder.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué ocurre esto?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución era sencilla, había que usar el protocolo IMAP en ves de POP3.